# DFS with accessing a map element inside. Time complexity

Tags: c++, graph, big-o, complexity-theory

I've got a directed graph represented by a map written in C++.

```
Node{
 vector<int> adjacency_list;
};
Graph{
 map<Node,Node> map;
};
```

I've got recursive DFS like(pseudocode):

```
dfs(node):
   for adjacent_node in node.adjacency_list:
       if(map[adjacent_node].valid):
          dfs(map[adjacent_node])
```

The complexity of C++ map [] operator is:

> Logarithmic in size.

I know that DFS in (adjacency list) directed graph is O(V+E) but I'm not sure what complexity this function gives me with this map [] operator.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is not clear from your pseudo code where the *map::operator[]* is called, since iterating through a *map* is usually done without it (in linear time).

Second, depending on the structure of the graph (i.e. is it a tree?) your algorithm might visit the same nodes multiple times, causing potentially exponential time complexity. If it contains directed loops, it won't ever terminate.

With the following C++ code, you would indeed get **O(V+E)** time complexity.

```
void dfs(Node& node) {
    if(node.visited) return;
    node.visited = true;
    for(Node& adj : node.adjacency_list) dfs(adj);
}
```

**EDIT:** Note that you would in fact get **O(E)** time complexity, but if E < V-1 you won't visit all nodes.

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry. I don't know how could such a mistake occurred. There should be called map[] inside. I made changes.

Comment: Since you call the logarithmic function every time you have passed an edge, it would be O(E*log(V)). You'd still have to make sure to stop at already visited nodes though!